# Creating min heap from array - 2 methods

Tags: python, arrays, algorithm, data-structures, heap

I am working on a problem about building a min heap from an array. I have 2 approaches - the first is recursion and the second is using a while loop. The recursion approach passed the tests on the online grader, but the while loop version doesn't seem to work. I generated some random stress tests in my code below and found that the 2 methods gave different answers as well.

May I know what's the mistake in my second method? The question is as follows:

> **Input Format.** The first line of the input contains single integer . The next line contains  space-separated
> integers .
>
> **Constraints.** 1 ≤  ≤ 100 000; 0 ≤ ,  ≤  − 1; 0 ≤ <sub>0</sub>, <sub>1</sub>,..., <sub>−1</sub> ≤ 109. All  are distinct.
>
> **Output Format.** The first line of the output should contain single integer  — the total number of swaps.
>
> must satisfy conditions 0 ≤  ≤ 4. The next  lines should contain the swap operations used to convert the array  into a heap. Each swap is described by a pair of integers ,  — the 0-based
> indices of the elements to be swapped. After applying all the swaps in the specified order the array must become a heap, that is, for each  where 0 ≤  ≤  − 1 the following conditions must be true:
>
> 1. If 2 + 1 ≤  − 1, then  < <sub>2+1</sub>.
> 2. If 2 + 2 ≤  − 1, then  < <sub>2+2</sub>.
>
> Note that all the elements of the input array are distinct. Note that any sequence of swaps that has length at most 4 and after which your initial array becomes a correct heap will be graded as correct.

My code:

```
# python3

from random import randint

swaps = []

def sift_down(i, n, data):
    min_index = i
    left_child = 2*i + 1
    right_child = 2*i + 2
    if left_child < n and data[left_child] < data[min_index]:
        min_index = left_child
    if right_child < n and data[right_child] < data[min_index]:
        min_index = right_child
    if i != min_index:
        swaps.append([i, min_index])
        data[i], data[min_index] = data[min_index], data[i]
        sift_down(min_index, n, data)

def build_heap(data):
    n = len(data)
    for i in range(n//2, -1, -1):
        sift_down(i, n, data)

    return swaps

# wrong answer using while loop instead of recursion
def build_heap2(data):
    swap = []
    for i in range(len(data)-1, 0, -1):
        current_node = i
        prev_node = i // 2 if i % 2 != 0 else i // 2 - 1

        while data[prev_node] > data[current_node] and current_node != 0:
            swap.append((prev_node, current_node))
            data[prev_node], data[current_node] = data[current_node], data[prev_node]
            current_node = prev_node
            prev_node = current_node // 2 if current_node % 2 != 0 else current_node // 2 - 1

    return swap


def main():
    # n = int(input())
    # data = list(map(int, input().split()))
    # assert len(data) == n
    
    while True:
        n = randint(1, 100000)
        data = []
        data2 = []
        for i in range(n):
            data.append(randint(0, 10^9))
        data2 = data.copy()
        
        swaps = build_heap(data)
        swaps2 = build_heap2(data2)
        
        
        if swaps != swaps2:
            print("recursion")
            print(data[0], len(data), len(swaps))
            print("loop:")
            print(data2[0], len(data2), len(swaps2))
            break
        
        else:
            print("success")
    
    swaps = build_heap(data)

    print(len(swaps))
    for i, j in swaps:
        print(i, j)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `build_heap2` implements an idea that is not correct. It starts from the bottom of the tree (correct), but then bubbles values *up* the tree (wrong), in the upper part of the tree that has not been heapified yet. This is not good. Not only can it report the wrong number of swaps, it will not always deliver a valid heap. For instance, for `[3, 1, 2, 4, 0]` the result after the swaps is still not a heap, as the value 1 ends up as a child of 3.

The purpose is to build little heaps at the bottom of the tree and after the children of a parent node have been turned into heaps, the value in that parent node is sifted *down* into either of these child-heaps. This is right, as now the moving value is moving *within* a subtree that is already heapified. The result is that the parent of these two little heaps is now the root of a valid heap itself. And so at the end of the algorithm, the root will be the root of a valid heap.

So instead of swapping values upwards in the tree, you need to swap downwards (choosing the child with the least value).

Here is the corrected version:

```
def build_heap(data):
    swap = []
    # We can start at the deepest parent:
    for i in range(len(data) // 2 - 1, -1, -1):
        current_node = i
        
        while True:
            child_node = current_node * 2 + 1
            if child_node >= len(data):
                break
            if child_node + 1 < len(data) and data[child_node + 1] < data[child_node]:
                child_node += 1
            if data[current_node] < data[child_node]:
                break
            # swap the current value DOWN, with the least of both child values
            swap.append((child_node, current_node))
            data[child_node], data[current_node] = data[current_node], data[child_node]
            current_node = child_node
    return swap
```

Comment: That's precisely what their first `build_heap` does, isn't it?

Comment: @rici, yes, but in iterative way, which is what the Asker was attempting to do.

Answer (score 1):

There are (at least) two ways to build a heap.

The O(N) solution works backwards from the middle of the dataset towards the beginning, ensuring that each successive element is the correct root of the subtree at that point:

```
def build_heap_down(data):
    n = len(data)
    for subtree in range(n // 2 - 1, -1, -1):
        sift_down(subtree, n, data)
```

The other solution, which is O(N log N), just adds each element in turn to a successively larger heap:

```
def build_heap_up(data):
    for new_element in range(1, n):
        sift_up(new_element, data)
```

Since `build_heap_up()` is log-linear in the worst case (which I believe is reverse-sorted input), it probably doesn't satisfy the needs of your assignment, which impose a linear bound on the number of swaps. Still, some experimentation is worth doing. Perhaps that's the point of this assignment.

```
def sift_up(elt, data):
    while elt > 0:
        parent = (elt - 1) // 2
        if data[parent] <= data[elt]: return
        swap(parent, elt, data)
        elt = parent

def sift_down(elt, limit, data):
    while True:
        kid = 2 * elt + 1
        if kid >= limit: return
        if kid + 1 < limit and data[kid + 1] < data[kid]: kid += 1
        if data[elt] <= data[kid]: return
        swap(elt, kid, data)
        elt = kid
```

The key insight here is that both `sift_up` and `sift_down` require that the array they are working with be a heap except for the element being sifted. `sift_down` works with the array from the sifted element to the end, so doing it correctly on the entire array requires working backwards. `sift_up` works with the array from the beginning to the sifted element, so the iteration has to work forwards.

Your `build_heap` does `build_heap_down`, as far as I can see correctly. Although it uses recursion, it does the same thing as my loop above (and the version from [@trincot](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72417433/1566221)); recursion at the very end of a function can always be turned into a simple loop using [tail call elimination](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tail_call). (Some languages automatically perform this program transformation, but Python isn't one of them.)

Your `build_heap2` is an incorrect version of `build_heap_up` because it works backwards instead of working forwards. That's easy to fix. But don't expect it to produce the same heap, much less the same list of swaps. There are many possible heaps which can be built from a given list of numbers, which is why it's possible to find an O(N) algorithm for `build_heap` and not for `sort`.

Comment: thanks for your explanation! To clarify, is there an explanation why the same heap won't be generated for the same given array if build_heap_up or build_heap_down is used? I understand that build_heap is the first step for heap sort. But why does the property that 'many possible heaps can be built from a given list of numbers' lead to O(n) time complexity for build_heap but O(nlg(n)) for sort at best?

Comment: *V* (with *N* distinct elements) needs to be sorted. There are *N*! possible rearrangements of *V*; only one is sorted and we need to find it. We repeatedly compare two elements in *V*. Each comparison can at best eliminate half of the possibilities. So we need to do at least **log**2(*N*!) comparisons in order to reduce the number of possibilities to 1. Using [Stirling's approximation for factorial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation#Speed_of_convergence_and_error_estimates), **log**2(*N*!) is O(*N* **log** *N*). That's the minimum number of comparisons needed.

Comment: *V* (with *N* distinct elements) needs to be turned into a binary heap. It's not quite so simple to figure out [how many possible binary heaps of size *N*](https://oeis.org/A056971) there are, but it turns out that there are about *N*! / **exp** (*N*), where e is the ubiquitous constant of Euler, 2.71828... It doesn't matter which possibility we select, and the division by an exponential cancels out the **log** *N* term in the number of comparisons needed. So in principle, it's possible that only O(N) comparisons are necessary, and `build_heap_down` demonstrates that the possibility is real.

Comment: @Young42 As for the question, why do `build_heap_up` and `build_heap_down` produce different heaps: Why should they produce the same heap? There are so many possible heaps to choose from and the algorithms are completely different; they work on the data elements in opposite orders. If they magically produced the same heap, that would require explanation.